# Partial search using query_string in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

My index has 1 million documents. I want to add a partial search functionality for my documents so I am using the following query: (to search "mall")

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*mall*",
      "default_operator": "OR",
      "fields": ["title^6", "fulltext"]
    }
  }
}
```

Is above query is proper for partial search?

Does it affect the search performance if document count increases?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of discussions for a partial search in various search engines, pretty feasible to find in the internet a lot of options and solutions.

Your query seems too be working for that. The performance will be the worst with "*word*" because the engine should look through all texts of all records. It's okay on small datasets (when there is no need to use ES), but becomes worse quickly enough. It's better to use [fulltext search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/term-vs-full-text.html) (for separate words divided by spaces or anything you want, it's a default mode for ES - just use [analyzed fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) and don't use "*") or preprocessing (extract "mall" and other search terms when populating ES). Also ["prefix" query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) works okay if it fits the requirements. If the [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) is slow then [N-grams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) are used for a partial search.